# centerInParent button in a RelativeLayout wrapped in a ScrollView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-scrollview, android-relativelayout

I have a button center in a RelativeLayout, and two images below the button.
I have two issues when I wrap my RelativeLayout in a ScrollView :

- the button is now centered in the relativelayout including the scrollable part. That's not what I want, I want to keep it centered in the part of the screen that I see without scrolling.
- my images below my centerInParent button are not below the button anymore. It works as if the button was in the top left corner.

So the images are below a white space at the top as if the button was there, and the button is centered in my layout but not as I want it to be :D

Here is my code :

```
<ScrollView 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:background="#E74E4C"
        android:paddingLeft="24dp"
        android:paddingRight="24dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageone"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/button"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/myimage" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imagetwo"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/imageone"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/myimagetwo" />

</RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Do you see what's wrong ? For info I intend to add a bottom navigation bar then.

Here is what I want and what I get :[image]

Comment: The button centering in the relative layout, and not just onscreen, is expected.  It centers relative to the parent.  The parent is the relative layout, not the screen.

Comment: @Alex9494 Hey can you post what you get an what you what you want to get?

Comment: @Charuka Hi, I have just updated my question with a drawing

Comment: @GabeSechan Yes I understand the logic. But its not what I want to get :)

Comment: @Alex9494 hey so you want to position image 1 after your button right ? is that the problem or you want to keep the button in the middle without scrolling but the images

Comment: @Charuka I want image 1 after the button (and image 2 after image 1),  I want to keep the button in the middle of the "visible screen when the activity is first opened", and I want to be able to scroll all the elements.

Comment: @Alex9494 great i ll have a look an let you know

Comment: @Alex9494 do you still need an answer i can post a one let me know :)

Comment: @Charuka Yes I need :)

Comment: @Alex9494 did you tried that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Programmatically give topMargin based on the ratio and you are done! If you want to adjust you can change values doesn't matter which screen it gets display same ratio will be there.

Here is my xml slight different than yours - (change ids i just add ones )

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/rel"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#000"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal">

    <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <RelativeLayout

                android:id="@+id/lin"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                    android:background="#E74E4C"
                    android:gravity="bottom"
                    android:paddingLeft="24dp"
                    android:paddingRight="24dp" />
            </RelativeLayout>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageone"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="250dp"
                android:layout_margin="16dp"
                android:background="#FFF"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imagetwo"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="250dp"
                android:layout_margin="16dp"
                android:background="#7823"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop" />


        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

code

```
  private int screenHeight;
    private int screenWidth;
    private RelativeLayout relativeLayout;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.web);
        relativeLayout =(RelativeLayout)  findViewById(R.id.lin);


        Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
        Point size = new Point();
        display.getSize(size);
        screenHeight = size.y;
        screenWidth = size.x;

        LinearLayout.LayoutParams relBtn = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        relBtn.topMargin = ((1920/2) *screenHeight/1920); // ratio based mine height is 1920 so to get it to middle i give half height, will be same in your mobiles too , you can change 1920/2 as you like 
        relativeLayout.setLayoutParams(relBtn);


    }
```

---

same thing with `RelativeLayout.LayoutParams`

xml:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:text="HELLO"
            android:textColor="#FFF"
            android:textSize="20dp" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/lin"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="50dp"

                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                android:gravity="bottom"
                android:paddingLeft="24dp"
                android:paddingRight="24dp" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageone"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="250dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/lin"
            android:layout_margin="16dp"
            android:background="@drawable/girl"
            android:scaleType="fitXY" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imagetwo"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="250dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/imageone"
            android:layout_margin="16dp"
            android:background="@drawable/amanda"
            android:scaleType="fitXY" />


    </RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

code :

```
private int screenHeight;
    private int screenWidth;
    private TextView textView;
    private RelativeLayout relativeLayout;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.web);
        relativeLayout =(RelativeLayout)  findViewById(R.id.lin);
        textView =(TextView)  findViewById(R.id.tv);


        Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
        Point size = new Point();
        display.getSize(size);
        screenHeight = size.y;
        screenWidth = size.x;


        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams tv = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        tv.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
        tv.topMargin = ((100)*screenHeight/1920); // ratio based mine height is 1920 so to get it to middle i give half height, will be same in your mobiles too , you can change 1920/2 as you like
        textView.setLayoutParams(tv);

        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams relBtn = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        relBtn.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
        relBtn.topMargin = ((1920/2 - 100 ) *screenHeight/1920); // ratio based mine height is 1920 so to get it to middle i give half height, will be same in your mobiles too , you can change 1920/2 as you like

        relativeLayout.setLayoutParams(relBtn);




    }
```

output :

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thank you, it does what I wanted ! I changed one line in java code (relBtn.topMargin = (screenHeight/2);) to avoid numbers such as 1920, I think it works. I also added a negative marginTop to my scrollview of half of my button height so that the button is perfectly centered (without that it is the top of the button that is centered). One more question : how to add content over the centered button ? I know, I should have said that before :D Content that can be scrolled with the button and the images below. I want this content centered between the top of the button and the top of the screen.

Comment: @Alex9494First 1920 for height and 1080 for width those are standers sizes you wont have problems with them if you use ratios i have used them in many apps, but you can use as you like :) .Second up-votes needed for further info .. haha . Over the centered button means .. behind it or what elaborate plz

Comment: If you want to add a view in between button and top of the screen its simple do the same that i did. add a view that you want before button. Initialize it ,use code do the same for the height give the height you want to have margin top .. you can also use `relBtn.leftMargin = (( leftMarginValue) *screenWidth/1080);` if you want to move it horizontaly

Comment: Also note that i have used  `LinearLayout.LayoutParams` but you can use  `RelativeLayout.LayoutParams` as well ....how you decide what to use is based on their parent , here scroll view child i have used a `LinearLayout` so that's why i used  `LinearLayout.LayoutParams`.. Also i think you know the difference between LinearLayout n RelativeLayout . If you use `RelativeLayout.LayoutParams` you gets a bit advantage cuz you can add new views and position them relatively

Comment: @Alex9494  added relative positioning too , you changed your acquirement so you can try second way as well added view in between button and top :)) if you like it hit up vote ;)

Comment: Thank you @Charuka, I've succeeded in doing what I wanted :)

Answer (score 0):

Eventually, I managed to get this, replace with your values:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="#E74E4C"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="167dp" />


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imagetwo"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/button"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageone"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/imagetwo"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

</RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you but the button is not centered in the "visible screen when the activity is opened". The 167dp marginTop you added enables not to get the button at the top of the screen, but it's not centered as I'd like it to be.

Comment: actually the length of `RelativeLayout` is not fixed because it has mode view at the end and it gradually increases with view. Making a view at center will not be accurate everytime.

Comment: If u persist u can create 2 view half half way and in one view add the button and on 2nd view add images. just assume in my image divide the layout into 2 and in one half add button soo that it will be fixed and on second add images.

Answer (score 0):

OR

Try this with 2 layouts:[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:id="@+id/rl">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:background="#E74E4C"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="71dp" />
    </RelativeLayout>


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imagetwo"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/rl"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageone"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/imagetwo"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />





</RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: The button is not centered in the "visible screen when the activity is opened". I have the same problem as with our first try, the 300dp relativelayout height enables not to get the button at the top of the screen but it's not centered as I'd like it to be. I tried with two LinearLayout with same weight and button at the bottom of the first linearlayout, but it doesnt work when I add the scrollview (the height of each lineralayout is not half of the visible screen but half of the whole scrollview I think)

Comment: Atleast I tried and it was kinda working, worth upvote... Haha

Comment: Yes thank you for having tried, as you said its "kinda" working. And kinda not working ;)